# how to asigne index jquery index value in to html

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Please suggest me what shuld I do to asigne jquery result to my html .
Here is script of jquery.

```
 success:function(data){
         $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(index, value){
         $.each(value.lineItems, function(index, item){
         console.log(item.totalTax);
        });
        });
}
```

Output is

```
{
    "data": {
        "lineItems": [{
            "customer": {
                "customerCode": {
                    "classCode": "DATA",
                    "isBusinessIndicator": false,
                    "value": "BOO1234"
                },
                "destination": {
                    "city": "hudew",
                    "country": "INDIA",
                    "postalCode": "201301",
                    "streetAddress1": "dwdwe",
                    "taxAreaId": "50591530"
                },
                "isTaxExempt": false,
                "taxRegistrations": []
            },
            "extendedPrice": 200.0,
            "fairMarketValue": 200.0,
            "product": {
                "value": "srvice123"
            },
            "quantity": {
                "unitOfMeasure": "EA",
                "value": 1.0
            },
            "seller": {
                "company": "Production",
                "taxRegistrations": []
            },
            "taxIncludedIndicator": false,
            "taxes": [{
                "calculatedTax": 12.0,
                "calculationRuleId": {
                    "salesTaxHolidayIndicator": false,
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "v1262305"
                },
                "effectiveRate": 0.06,
                "exempt": 0.0,
                "imposition": {
                    "impositionId": "v1j2398",
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "Sales and Use Tax"
                },
                "impositionType": {
                    "impositionTypeId": "v1",
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "General Sales and Use Tax"
                },
                "inclusionRuleId": {
                    "salesTaxHolidayIndicator": false,
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "v1280125"
                },
                "isService": false,
                "jurisdiction": {
                    "effectiveDate": "1900-01-01",
                    "expirationDate": "9999-12-31",
                    "jurisdictionId": "2398",
                    "jurisdictionType": "STATE",
                    "value": "INDIA"
                },
                "maxTaxIndicator": false,
                "nominalRate": 0.06,
                "nonTaxable": 0.0,
                "notRegisteredIndicator": false,
                "situs": "DESTINATION",
                "taxCollectedFromParty": "BUYER",
                "taxResult": "TAXABLE",
                "taxStructure": "SINGLE_RATE",
                "taxType": "SALES",
                "taxable": 200.0
            }, {
                "calculatedTax": 2.5,
                "calculationRuleId": {
                    "salesTaxHolidayIndicator": false,
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "v1080547"
                },
                "effectiveRate": 0.0125,
                "exempt": 0.0,
                "imposition": {
                    "impositionId": "v1j3262",
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "Local Sales and Use Tax"
                },
                "impositionType": {
                    "impositionTypeId": "v1",
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "General Sales and Use Tax"
                },
                "inclusionRuleId": {
                    "salesTaxHolidayIndicator": false,
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "v1287055"
                },
                "isService": false,
                "jurisdiction": {
                    "effectiveDate": "1900-01-01",
                    "expirationDate": "9999-12-31",
                    "jurisdictionId": "3262",
                    "jurisdictionType": "COUNTY",
                    "value": "ORANGE"
                },
                "maxTaxIndicator": false,
                "nominalRate": 0.0125,
                "nonTaxable": 0.0,
                "notRegisteredIndicator": false,
                "situs": "DESTINATION",
                "taxCollectedFromParty": "BUYER",
                "taxResult": "TAXABLE",
                "taxStructure": "SINGLE_RATE",
                "taxType": "SALES",
                "taxable": 200.0
            }, {
                "calculatedTax": 1.0,
                "calculationRuleId": {
                    "salesTaxHolidayIndicator": false,
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "v3696"
                },
                "effectiveRate": 0.005,
                "exempt": 0.0,
                "imposition": {
                    "impositionId": "v1j3263",
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "Local Sales and Use Tax"
                },
                "impositionType": {
                    "impositionTypeId": "v1",
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "General Sales and Use Tax"
                },
                "inclusionRuleId": {
                    "salesTaxHolidayIndicator": false,
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "v1288770"
                },
                "isService": false,
                "jurisdiction": {
                    "effectiveDate": "1900-01-01",
                    "expirationDate": "9999-12-31",
                    "jurisdictionId": "3263",
                    "jurisdictionType": "DISTRICT",
                    "value": "TRANSPORTATION AUTHORITY (OCTA)"
                },
                "maxTaxIndicator": false,
                "nominalRate": 0.005,
                "nonTaxable": 0.0,
                "notRegisteredIndicator": false,
                "situs": "DESTINATION",
                "taxCollectedFromParty": "BUYER",
                "taxResult": "TAXABLE",
                "taxStructure": "SINGLE_RATE",
                "taxType": "SALES",
                "taxable": 200.0
            }],
            "totalTax": 15.5,
            "transactionType": "SALE"
        }, {
            "customer": {
                "customerCode": {
                    "classCode": "RESELLER",
                    "isBusinessIndicator": false,
                    "value": "BOO1234"
                },
                "destination": {
                    "city": "hudew",
                    "country": "INDIA",
                    "postalCode": "92615",
                    "streetAddress1": "dwdwe",
                    "taxAreaId": "50591530"
                },
                "isTaxExempt": false,
                "taxRegistrations": []
            },
            "extendedPrice": 37.98,
            "fairMarketValue": 37.98,
            "product": {
                "value": "LGS270"
            },
            "quantity": {
                "unitOfMeasure": "EA",
                "value": 1.0
            },
            "seller": {
                "company": "PROduction",
                "taxRegistrations": []
            },
            "taxIncludedIndicator": false,
            "taxes": [{
                "calculatedTax": 2.28,
                "calculationRuleId": {
                    "salesTaxHolidayIndicator": false,
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "v1262305"
                },
                "effectiveRate": 0.06,
                "exempt": 0.0,
                "imposition": {
                    "impositionId": "v1j2398",
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "Sales and Use Tax"
                },
                "impositionType": {
                    "impositionTypeId": "v1",
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "General Sales and Use Tax"
                },
                "inclusionRuleId": {
                    "salesTaxHolidayIndicator": false,
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "v1280125"
                },
                "isService": false,
                "jurisdiction": {
                    "effectiveDate": "1900-01-01",
                    "expirationDate": "9999-12-31",
                    "jurisdictionId": "2398",
                    "jurisdictionType": "STATE",
                    "value": "India"
                },
                "maxTaxIndicator": false,
                "nominalRate": 0.06,
                "nonTaxable": 0.0,
                "notRegisteredIndicator": false,
                "situs": "DESTINATION",
                "taxCollectedFromParty": "BUYER",
                "taxResult": "TAXABLE",
                "taxStructure": "SINGLE_RATE",
                "taxType": "SALES",
                "taxable": 37.98
            }, {
                "calculatedTax": 0.47,
                "calculationRuleId": {
                    "salesTaxHolidayIndicator": false,
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "v1080547"
                },
                "effectiveRate": 0.0125,
                "exempt": 0.0,
                "imposition": {
                    "impositionId": "v1j3262",
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "Local Sales and Use Tax"
                },
                "impositionType": {
                    "impositionTypeId": "v1",
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "General Sales and Use Tax"
                },
                "inclusionRuleId": {
                    "salesTaxHolidayIndicator": false,
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "v1287055"
                },
                "isService": false,
                "jurisdiction": {
                    "effectiveDate": "1900-01-01",
                    "expirationDate": "9999-12-31",
                    "jurisdictionId": "3262",
                    "jurisdictionType": "COUNTY",
                    "value": "ORANGE"
                },
                "maxTaxIndicator": false,
                "nominalRate": 0.0125,
                "nonTaxable": 0.0,
                "notRegisteredIndicator": false,
                "situs": "DESTINATION",
                "taxCollectedFromParty": "BUYER",
                "taxResult": "TAXABLE",
                "taxStructure": "SINGLE_RATE",
                "taxType": "SALES",
                "taxable": 37.98
            }, {
                "calculatedTax": 0.19,
                "calculationRuleId": {
                    "salesTaxHolidayIndicator": false,
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "v3696"
                },
                "effectiveRate": 0.005,
                "exempt": 0.0,
                "imposition": {
                    "impositionId": "v1j3263",
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "Local Sales and Use Tax"
                },
                "impositionType": {
                    "impositionTypeId": "v1",
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "General Sales and Use Tax"
                },
                "inclusionRuleId": {
                    "salesTaxHolidayIndicator": false,
                    "userDefined": false,
                    "value": "v1288770"
                },
                "isService": false,
                "jurisdiction": {
                    "effectiveDate": "1900-01-01",
                    "expirationDate": "9999-12-31",
                    "jurisdictionId": "3263",
                    "jurisdictionType": "DISTRICT",
                    "value": "TRANSPORTATION AUTHORITY (OCTA)"
                },
                "maxTaxIndicator": false,
                "nominalRate": 0.005,
                "nonTaxable": 0.0,
                "notRegisteredIndicator": false,
                "situs": "DESTINATION",
                "taxCollectedFromParty": "BUYER",
                "taxResult": "TAXABLE",
                "taxStructure": "SINGLE_RATE",
                "taxType": "SALES",
                "taxable": 37.98
            }],
            "totalTax": 2.94,
            "transactionType": "SALE"
        }],
        "postingDate": "2022-11-01",
        "returnAssistedParametersIndicator": true,
        "roundAtLineLevel": false,
        "saleMessageType": "INVOICE",
        "subTotal": 237.98,
        "total": 256.42,
        "totalTax": 18.44,
        "transactionType": "SALE"
    }
}
```

I trying to insert these value in to html input

```
<input type="text" name="taxt" value="">
<input type="text" name="taxt" value="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `index` as the index into the DOM elements.

There's also no need for the first `$.each()`. `lineItems` is only in the `data` property, so just access that directly.

```
success:function(data){
    $.each(JSON.parse(data).data.lineItems, function(index, item){
        $("input[name=taxt]").eq(index).val(item.totalTax);
    });
}
```

Comment: Barmar@ Thanks ..But this is not sending value in input field

Comment: Barmar@ r you there?

Comment: @sanjayyadav well have you done any debugging yourself? Barmar showed you how to write data into the textbox, as you asked. But since we can't see what you're getting in the `data` variable, we can't tell you if there's a problem with your $.each loop logic which might prevent that being executed, and we can't see your browser console to know if maybe there was a JS error which stops it executing or something. You need to do some basic tests on your own code.

Comment: ADyson@ I am new with this and try to  solve this from long time.I  suppose Index is not working. Thank you for reply ADyson . could helm me regarding this

Comment: @sanjayyadav help in what way? I've just explained that we cannot see your data, and so we cannot run your code or know exactly what it will do. Use the Developer Tools in your browser (specifically in this case the Console and the JS debugger) to see what's happening with your code. Put the contents of `data` into your question if you want us to see it and be able to run the code ourselves. But debugging is a really basic skill that you need to learn in order to succeed as a programmer, so you should try it yourself first. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/

Comment: Adyson @I am updating question with code

Comment: ADyson@r you there?

Comment: Yes. But you haven't changed your question so there's nothing for me to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252885/discussion-between-sanjay-yadav-and-adyson).